# On the molybdenum(III) oxide-catalysed oxidation of alkanes to carbonyls

Tags: reaction-mechanism, water, alcohols, organic-oxidation

The following reaction is specified in my notes;
$$\ce{CH4 ->[Mo2O3, \Delta]HCHO}$$ The intermediate steps involve the dehydration of an alcohol to yield the final product.

Wouldn't this only work if there's acid in the reaction mixture? Or is it that water functions as a proton donor, inducing the protonation of the hydroxyl and causing the dehydration?

Comment: Is it not a reaction $\ce{CH4 + O2}$ ?

Comment: @Maurice: it was shown with $\ce{[O]}$ above the arrows in the reaction steps.

Comment: Sorry, There is no [O] above the arrow. There is only a molybdenum oxide

Comment: @Maurice: Yes, not in this simplified equation, but when you write it out, apparently you use nascent oxygen. It's the controlled oxidation of alkanes, to be specific.

Comment: The nature of the oxidizing agent should absolutely be given. Because it is the very heart of the problem. How is this "nascent oxygen" produced ? UV ? $\ce{H2O2}$ ? Spark ?

Comment: @Maurice: It's not specified, and I can't find the reaction online. I suppose it's not generally known.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any evidence, \*any evidence at all\*, that nascent hydrogen actually exists?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/131162/is-there-any-evidence-any-evidence-at-all-that-nascent-hydrogen-actually-exi)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The above depicts a concept, rather than an equation for that there is no balance of atoms on the left and right of the arrow.  Because if $\ce{Mo2O3}$ is said to be used *as catalyst* rather than a (stoichiometric) reagent, then the oxygen in formaldehyde must be of different origin than $\ce{Mo2O3}$.

On industrial scale, formaldehyde is prepared from [methanol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methanol#From_synthesis_gas) by an  heterogeneous redox-reaction.  The oxygen needed may come from oxygen gas, or simply air.  Thus, the last step known as [Formox process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formox_process) is

$$ \ce{2 CH3OH + O2 -> 2 CH2O + 2 H2O} $$

([from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formaldehyde#Industry))

$\ce{Mo2O3}$ is deployed ease the advancement of the reaction, i.e., to perform the wanted reaction at lower temperature (heating costs money) than without this help, and to further increase rate or / and yield of said reaction compared performing this conversion at room temperature.

Comment: So oxidising alkanes up the oxidation ladder isn't a thing?

Comment: @HarryHolmes Compared to other compounds, saturated hydrocarbons / alkanes are not very much reactive.  On occasion, you encounter them under the name «paraffin», derived from the Latin «parum» (little) and «afffinis» (related) to just describe their low reactivity in comparison to functionalized and unsaturated hydrocarbons.  It is easier e.g., to chop long alkane chains into smaller alkenes (e.g., in a steam cracker) and then to oxidize these fragments (e.g., Wacker process with ethylene to yield acetaldehyde, $\ce{MeCHO}$). Formally, the remove of hydrogen from alkanes is an oxidation, too.