# What is Nascent Hydrogen?

Tags: hydrogen

I am currently studying preparation of Alkane from Alkyl Halides (By Reduction)

But the term  "Nascent Hydrogen" Confuses me after reading diffrent threads and stuff

Please help :)

Comment: Perhaps see here for a previous time this popped up: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/131162/79678. Maybe a unicorn or maybe not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some dyes are reduced by a mixture of $\ce{Zn + HCl}$, and are not reduced by zinc alone or by $\ce{H2}$ alone. This reaction is attributed to  the hypothesis that the reducing agent is "nascent", or "atomic" hydrogen which could have been produced by a reaction like $$\ce{Zn + 2 H^+ -> Zn^{2+} + 2 H·}$$ which is usually followed by the dimerization $$\ce{2 H· -> H2}$$